# Creating a controller for a model using EF (No key error)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to create a controller with scaffolding based on the following model (with no previously created context, but I chose the option to create it alongside the controller):

```
namespace MvcMusicStorePractice.Models
{
    public class Album
    {     
        public virtual int AlbumId { get; set; }
        public virtual int GenreId { get; set; }
        public virtual int ArtistId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
        public virtual string AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }
        public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
        public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But I keep getting the following error:

> Album::EntityType 'Album' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

I'v tried the following solutions:

- Adding the `[Key]` attribute to the AlbumId;
- Changing the public virtual int AlbumId to simply public int Id.

It still does not work however. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the entity framework, every entity needs a key. This is how EF tracks objects in its cache, posts updates back to the underlying data store, and links related objects together:

```
namespace MvcMusicStorePractice.Models
{ 
    public class Album
    {   
        [Key]
        public int AlbumId { get; set; }
        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        public int ArtistId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }

        public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
        public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Mind the [key] annotation that will make that field the PK.

Also make sure to only use "Virtual" with foreign objects (Only Genre & Artist)/

Comment: Hey Jelle, thank you for your reply, but it still is giving me the same error message. The example is actually a practice example, so I'm not sure why it is not working. I'm naming the controller StoreManagerController like in the example. I know that this is not the convention, but surely that could not cause an error either. Note that my VS does accept the [Key] Annotation and does not give me an in-code error either.

Comment: I don't see the problem. I tested the class and created a controller. The problem is, it's not giving me any errors :(...

Comment: Hmmm I guess there's somehow something wrong with VS2015. I was already afraid that this was the problem (as I got some other (for me) unexplainable error). At least I know that the coding was correct then, and since I'm still learning, that is the main goal :) So still thank you for your time and answer!

Comment: No problem, I hope you fix the VS2015 issue soon, cause this can be a pain in the ass :).